# Javascript REPL from the command line

Tags: javascript, debugging, command-line, read-eval-print-loop

Whenever I am coding, I often find myself every now and then in a REPL to test out some concepts before I go ahead and implement it. For Ruby on Rails development I use [PRY](http://pryrepl.org/)and for python I use [bpython](https://bitbucket.org/bobf/bpython). Wondering whether there is an equivalent for that in javascript. Basically testing out javascript code from the terminal

Comment: You mean like node.js?

Comment: You can also open up any browsers developer console, not quite the command line but does a good job for quick stuff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though I usually have a JavaScript-enabled browser open, I often find myself using the [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) REPL.

Just run `node` in a command prompt, and it will open a REPL for you.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use node.js :

```
$ node
> 1 + 1
> 2
>
```

Although, this won't work for usual browser element (`window`, `document`) and DOM. If you want a browser environnement, checkout [Phantomjs REPL](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/REPL) and Casperjs - although I'm not sure about their capacity.

Comment: Great! I didn't know PhantomJS can be used as REPL via CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js offers a REPL, although you probably aren't looking to get into Node in general.